# Parsing CSV in Python 101

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I'm trying to understand/visualise the process of parsing a raw csv data file in `Python` from `dataquest.io`'s training course.

I understand that `rows = data.split('\n')` splits the long string of csv file into rows based on where the line break is. ie:

```
day1, sunny, \n day2, rain \n
```

becomes

```
day1, sunny
day2, rain
```

I thought the `for` loop would further break the data into something like:

```
day 1 
sunny 
day 2 
rain
```

Instead the course seems to imply it would actually become a list of lists usefully. I don't understand, why does that happen?

```
weather_data = []

f = open("la_weather.csv", 'r')
data = f.read()
rows = data.split('\n')
for row in rows:
    split_row = row.split(",")
    weather_data.append(split_row)
```

Comment: Actually you are reading the csv file as a normal text file .To use it has a csv method you have to use csv reader module

Comment: And if you want to parse all the data with in `,` u could use split(",") instaed

Comment: what you want to append in the weather data

Comment: Everything i can google points me towards using a dedicated csv reader module. I am just starting out to learn python but i guess this is the way how people do in an actual python environment? i m guessing data quest is trying to illustrate a concept which i couldn't follow.

Comment: If you don't want to use python means it can be done in that way to what do you want to append in the weather list

Comment: in the training it said after this set of codes, it will become something like a spreadsheet table layout

Day   Weather Type
1        sunny
2        rainy
3        foggy

Comment: so you want to append the climate into the list right

Comment: yes - and weather_data is empty to begin with

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj7nutlo1jf66bj/Screenshot%202015-06-12%2017.16.03.png?dl=0

couldn't post image directly but this is a screenshot from the data quest training

Comment: will there always be a weather data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm ignoring the CSV stuff and concentrating just on your list misunderstanding. When you split the row of text, it becomes a list of strings. That is, `rows` becomes: `["day1, sunny","day2, rain"]`.

The `for` statement, applied to a list, iterates through the elements of that list. So, on the first time through `row` will be `"day1, sunny"`, the second time through it will be `"day2, rain"`, etc.

Inside each iteration of the for loop, it creates a new list, by splitting row at the commas into, eg, `["day1"," sunny"]`. All of these lists are added to the weather_data list you created at the start. You end up with a list of lists, ie `[['day1', ' sunny'], ['day2', ' rain']]`. If you wanted `['day1', ' sunny', 'day2', ' rain']`, you could do:

```
for row in rows:
     split_row = row.split(",")
     for ele in split_row:
         weather_data.append(ele)
```

Comment: ["day1, sunny","day2, rain"] - for instance there are two rows in the data before the for loop. The author/course suggested after the for loop, it will become two rows and two columns (with the weather type as column two).

Why wouldn't it actually be broken down  into ["day1"," sunny","day2", "rain"] - 4 rows?

the for loop is only asking to break off whenever it sees a comma.

Comment: I answered further, sorry for not fully answering to begin with.

Comment: what is the expected output of this program as of now it gives output like `[["day1","sunny"],["day2","rainy"]]`

Answer (score 1):

That code *does* make it a list of lists.

As you say, the first `split` converts the data into a list, one element per line.

Then, for each line, the second `split` converts it into another list, one element per column.

And then the second list is appended, as a single item, to the `weather_data` list - which is now, as the instructions say, a list of lists.

Note that this code isn't very good - quite apart from the fact that you would always use the `csv` module, as others have pointed out, you would *never* do `f.read()` and then split the result. You would just do `for line in f` which automatically iterates over each row.

Answer (score 0):

As a more pythonic and flexible way for dealing with [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) files you can use `csv` module, instead of reading it as a raw text:

```
import csv
with open("la_weather.csv", 'rb') as f:
  spamreader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
  for row in spamreader:
      #do stuff
```

Here `spamreader` is a reader object and you can get the rows as tuple with looping over it.

And if you want to get all of rows within a list you can just convert the `spamreader` to list :

```
with open("la_weather.csv", 'rb') as f:
  spamreader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
  print list(spamreader)
```